# Who is Death talking to at the end of "Death: The High Cost of Living"?

Tags: character-identification, the-sandman, vertigo-comics

In Neil Gaiman's *Death - The High Host of Living*, at the end when Death returns back from her mortal form, we see someone was waiting for her; who was this person she was talking to?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It's Death herself.

Here's the full panel:

[image]
<sub>Click for full resolution</sub>

As a part of her duties, once a century Death has to take a mortal form and live a day among living things. I interpreted Didi as a temporary Avatar for Death. In the same way as
<sub>spoilers from the ending of *The Sandman* series!</sub>

> Daniel Hall became the next Dream,

Didi became Death. But also remained Didi. She is both Death, and Didi.

[image]